# To high power consumption 2x RX 470 8G - 575 watts - How to fix?

Tags: mining, ether, gpu, power-consumption

My miner is runnig for a few days and today i checkt the power consumption with a special device. The consumption is around 575 Watts.
I had assumed that it will be around 300 Watts.
Why is the consumption this high and how kan i fix it ?

**Rig:**
2x MSI Radeon RX 470 8G

Intel Core i5 4460

Gigabyte GA-Z97P-D3

4GB Corsair 1600 MHz

Corsair 60 GB SSD

Corsair RM750x Gold

EthOS 1.1

**Settings:**

globaldriver amdgpu

globalpowertune 4

globalminer claymore

maxgputemp 75

globalfan 85

stratumproxy enabled

proxywallet 0xE06d6425AA9bf1F609278999Fe6504f7D2A8C5E6

proxypool1 pool-eu.ethosdistro.com:5001

proxypool2 pool-usa.ethosdistro.com:5001

flags --cl-global-work 8192 --farm-recheck 200

**Mining arround 42 MH/s.**

***How can help me?***

**Update:**
I orderd a third card from another supplier. It's from a diffrent batch as well.
I swapped al the cards tried them single, double and with three of them.
It doesn't matter or i swap the card from different batches i get the same power consumption every time.

Minig with only 1 card: 305 Watt.
Minig with 2 cards: 570 Watt
Minig with 3 cards: 819 Watt.

This doesn't seem right

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarks gives around 157 to 163w for this model. So you probably are in the high value due to the fact that mining is a heavy work. So 326w or a bit more for your cards. The rest of your system use 249w, this is a bit high too but it depends of a lot of things. Higher temperature due to mining can elevate the consumption but i admit you are almost twice the value on the rest of the pc. Try removing each graphic card and calculate the consumption of the pc without this load, then add card one after the other an mine and see if one have an abnormal consumption. Hard to say more...

Comment: Thank you - Nicolas Massart.


Update:
I orderd a third card from another supplier. It's from a diffrent batch as well.
I swapped al the cards tried them single, double and with three of them.
It doesn't matter or i swap the card from different batches i get the same power consumption every time.

Minig with only 1 card: 305 Watt.
Minig with 2 cards: 570 Watt
Minig with 3 cards: 819 Watt.

This doesn't seem right

Comment: @Duratek are you sure of your power meter?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you checked the power consumption at the wall with a device like [this](https://cdn01.ovonni.com/uploads/2017/201703/20170323/heditor/201703231639493238.jpg), then the total consumption (at the wall) heavily depends on the Power Supply Unit (PSU) as well. If the PSU isn't +85% efficient then a lot of power goes wasted.

PSU efficiency of 70% means that for every 100W drawn from the power outlet at the wall, you get 70W of power for your computer parts.

Let's say each of your cards draws around 160W and the rest of the system around 80W, for a total of 400W (160+160+80). If the efficiency of the PSU is 70% then you'll get a reading at the wall around 570W!

Kindly check your PSU and if it's anything less than 85%, I suggest you replace it.

You might as well want to check the following:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_Plus